# Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1, how can be handled

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

how can be handle the error in this code which give out this message 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

in order to send packet from client to server using udp socket

```
    public class DatagramServer
{
 private final static int PACKETSIZE = 100 ;

public static void main( String args[] )
{
  // Check the arguments
  if( args.length != 0 )
  {
     System.out.println( "usage: DatagramServer port" ) ;
     return ;
  }

  try
  {
     // Convert the argument to ensure that is it valid
     int port = Integer.parseInt( args[1] ) ;

     // Construct the socket
     DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket( port ) ;

     System.out.println( "The server is ready..." ) ;



  }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `if` statement to check for equals, i.e

`if( args.length == 0 )`

or use `1` instead of `0`, i.e.

`if( args.length != 1 )`

The current code means that the `Integer.parseInt()` statement is reached only when `args` has a length of `0`, so by addressing `args[0]` you are trying to index the first position of an empty array.

Comment: Thanks, it works, however I need it to go to try statement, but it stays in IF statement

Comment: If it stays in the `if`` statement for both cases, then you do not pass the argument. How do you invoke the

Answer (score 2):

Array elements start at index zero, not `1`:

```
int port = Integer.parseInt( args[0] ) ;  // first argument is args[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it keeps giving me the same problem